# What would be the best way to learn YII framework?

Tags: php, yii

I have used codeigniter for developing websites and now I am switching to Yii. Can someone please suggest me what would be the best way to learn YII framework?

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com

Comment: Just google it. you will get more tutorial.

Comment: to concentrate on learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link would be enough to learn basic usage

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/268/how-to-learn-yii/

Answer (score 0):

There's a documentation section on [the official web](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/). Start there + simply start writing in Yii.